# How do I make a username input only accept numbers and letters in php?

Tags: php, mysql

So users have been creating accounts and some includes %20, how do I get the input to only accept a-z, A-Z, and 0-9?

```
if ($username === null){$registrable = false; array_push($error,'Not a valid Username.');}
```

**Can it be similar to the code above?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a normal text input? If so you can try using **pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-]+"** on the input.
If the pattern is not correct when submitting the form, users will get a message asking them to use the propper pattern.

Answer (score 0):

use in php [ctype_alnum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php)

```
if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
    echo "username is aplphanumeric!\n";
} else {
    echo "The usename $username is not valid\n";
}
```